# backbone.js: how to inline editing on attribute of a model

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js

how would i add inline editing on attributes of a model,

for example, when i have a `Player` model

```
var Player = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    id: 0,
    name: '',
    points: 0
  },
  initialize: function(){
    // irrelevant stuff happening here...
  },
  rename: function(newName){
    this.set({ name: newName });
  }
});
```

and a `playerRow` view

```
var PlayerRow = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'li',
  className: 'player',
  events: { 
    'click span.score':  'score',
    'blur input.name': 'rename',
    'click div.playername': 'renderRename'
  },   
  initialize: function(){
    _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'rename');
    this.model.bind('change', this.render);
  },
  render: function(){
    var template = Tmpl.render("playerRow", { model : this.model });
    $(this.el).html(template);
    return this;
  },
  renderRename: function() {
    // i was thinking of switching the DOM into a textfield here
  },
  rename: function(){
    var inpt = $(this.el).find('input.name');
    var newName = (inpt.val() != '') ? inpt.val() : 'no-name';
    this.model.rename(newName);
  }
});
```

and my playerRow template

```
<script type="text/template" id="playerRow-template">
  <% if ( model.get('name') == '' ) { %>
    <div class="state-edit"><input type="text" class="name" name="name"></input></div>
  <% } else { %>    
    <div class="playername"><%= model.get('name') %></div>
  <% } %>
</script>
```

either i set a certain property of my model that holds the state (default or edit), which triggers a re-render and in my template instead of testing `if name == ''` i can test on that state property.

or i do it inline like i say in my comment in renderRename i just swap the DOM into an input field  but i think this is a bad way to do it. Would this cause troubles with the already bound events? like `'blur input.name': 'rename'`

i doubt creating a new view for the edit is the best way, because i want inline editing, for just this one name field, i don't want all the rest of the player template to be duplicate in the player template and the editplayer template.

**so, bottomline, my question:
what is the best way, to handle inline editing**

1. a separate view
2. inline just appending an input field (don't know if this works well with the bound events)
3. having my model hold a state variable for this attribute (would work but sounds weird to have a model hold view related data)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A different option altogether:

Inline edititing making use of the html EditableContent feature. No need for changing/cluttering the DOM, great user experience if done correctly, supported in all major browsers.

A couple of js-editors make use of this, most notably [Aloha Editor](http://www.aloha-editor.org) (check for browser support), but for attribute editing without needing much else (e.g rich text editing etc) you can easily roll your own.

**EDIT: June 2012:**

Rolling your own becomes much easier when using the excellent range Library: 
http://code.google.com/p/rangy/

Hth,
Geert-Jan

Comment: thanks for the idea, but i'd rather have it swap to an input field.

Comment: You're free to do so of course, but I'm curious to the why. For cosmetic reasons there's no reason to do the input-route instead of the contentEditable, after all: You can style the content-editable (in edit-state) any way you like, including making it look like an input field. I'm curious to know any other reasons actually.

Comment: indeed Aloha-editor may be overkill. But the underlying feature contenteditable is really low level (part of html spec). (just do : <div contenteditable="true">input here </div>  to make an editable div. Swapping in the contenteditable='true' part would be the only thing required for switching between view and edit-state, but indeed it still requires some dom-manipulation (as does the swapping in an input-field for a div) .. if you do start looking into contenteditabledo a quick search on stackoverflow to see some of the common pitfalls (copy/paste can be a problem , no support on mobile)

Comment: btw: your events will still be bound, so that part will work automatically. Enough promo already ;)

Comment: If you have a datetime field or some other similar field you would want the field to show as a fancy input for usability reasons; since that field shows up as a input you would want all other fields to show as inputs; since you have one place where you convert to inputs, for consistency (again usability) you would want everywhere else in your application to use inputs. So unless you know for sure plain text is all you'll ever need it's better to do a conversion to inputs, as fancy as not converting might sound.

Answer (score 0):

I like to have an extra input field in the view that is hidden by default. (This is closest to your option (2), but it avoids conditionals in the template or adding elements on-the-fly.)

So the template might look something like this:

```
<div class="show-state">
    ... <%= name %> ...
    <input type="button" value="edit"/>
</div>
<div class="edit-state">   <!-- hidden with display: none in CSS -->
    ... <input type="text" value="<%= name %>"/> ...
</div>
```

Essentially, it's a view with two states, "showing" and "editing". When the user clicks "edit", I call `this.$('.show-state').hide(); this.$('.edit-state').show();` to flip the state.

Once the edit gets submitted or canceled, I just have the view rerender itself (after talking to the server and updating the model's attributes if necessary) to revert to the original "show" state and reset the input field.

P.S. Keep in mind that my code enables XSS because it does not escape `name`.